# distroless java docker image error

Tags: java, docker

When I attempt to create a docker image using the distroless java base image,
I get the following error when I include any shell command like 'mkdir' , 'chmod'
any help on this is really appreciated.

> OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown

Comment: See this answer for a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57395265/2799191

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [list of things in the distroless base image](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/master/base/README.md) it just doesn't include a shell, or mkdir, or chmod, or anything else like that.  The [Java image](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/tree/master/java) adds the JVM, and that's it.  It's probably not going to be possible to build an image based on that that does much more than `COPY` in a prebuilt jar and set a `CMD` to point to it, maybe setting some default `ENV` variables along the way.

If you need the base tools that are included in a standard Linux distribution, then you want to start from a more featureful base image like the standard [openjdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) image.

Comment: David,Thanks for the response. Based on my searches on "google" and your answer, looks like the distroless java thing is meant only for toy projects at this time. I cant seem to even set a shell script as the entrypoint using the recommended ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"] and hence I cant set things like JAVA_OPTS and other env vars.

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/issues/168

Answer (score 8):

`distroless` provides a `debug` image that contains a shell so that you can `exec` into it:

```
gcr.io/distroless/java:debug
```

The `debug` images contain busybox. You can run this image with Docker by:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint "/busybox/sh" gcr.io/distroless/java:debug
```

If you would like to build a Java Docker image directly in a Maven or Gradle project using `distroless` as the base, check out [Jib](https://github.com/google/jib).

Answer (score 1):

distroless provides a debug image that contains a shell . In pom or running docker from command prompt :

Steps as below :

**Pom Change :**

```
<from>
    <image>gcr.io/distroless/java:11-debug</image>
</from>
```

**docker command:**

docker exec -it  sh